# Swift-MVP: Function is not called in the presenter delegate. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swift, uikit, mvp

Can someone explain to me why this simple MVP implementation is not working? The `addressDemoViewControllerDidTap` method in the `AddressDemoPresenter` extension is not called. Everything seems ok to me, but I am probably missing something.

```
final class AddressDemoPresenter {
    private weak var addressDemoViewController: AddressDemoViewController?

    func makeAddressDemoViewController() -> UINavigationController {
        let demoViewController = AddressDemoViewController()
        addressDemoViewController = demoViewController
        demoViewController.delegate = self
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: demoViewController)
    }
}

extension AddressDemoPresenter: AddressDemoViewControllerDelegate {
    func addressDemoViewControllerDidTap(_ addressDemoViewController: AddressDemoViewController) {
        print("FOO")
    }
}

// VIEW CONTROLLER

protocol AddressDemoViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func addressDemoViewControllerDidTap(_ addressDemoViewController: AddressDemoViewController)
}

final class AddressDemoViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: AddressDemoViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Address Form", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
}

private extension AddressDemoViewController {
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        delegate?.addressDemoViewControllerDidTap(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `delegate?.addressDemoViewControllerDidTap(self)` called? If yes, is the delegate `nil`? Where is the call of `makeAddressDemoViewController()`? Which objects holds the `AddressDemoPresenter` instance?

Comment: The problem was in the app delegate as an instance of DemoPresenter was not being held by any object. Thank you